# Heart Beat Detection with Camera

Tags: android, camera, detection, heartbeat

I am searching for a library to detect heart beats using an android phone's camera. As far as i see, apps with this capability use two ways:

- Placing your finger tip on the camera lens and watching the changes in frames in camera.
- Watching your face(not sure what they do later :)) with the front camera

Tried the application [here](https://github.com/phishman3579/android-heart-rate-monitor) but it does not seem to be correct when compared to the popular apps on the market. it actually made me worried at first.

**Anyone used such a library for free or with a price? Thanks**

Comment: I don't have an answer for now, just curious: in which context are you going to use such an app?

Comment: we have an application which talks(through bluetooth) with the real health devices and fetches measured values to show the changes in history. If we can find such a library this feature would be integrated into the app.

Comment: `detect heart beats using an android phone's camera.` So, you want to **see** the **sound** of your heart?! Wouldn't your **microphone** do a better job?

Comment: well, I really don't think, that any app can compete with any medical device in terms of accuracy. What you are trying to achieve looks like an on-line pregnancy test joke, with accuracy rate of 49% :)

Comment: I can imagine using a gravity/acceleration sensor for that...

Comment: I can imagine that using the built-in antiproton deceleration sensor will be doing an even better job... ;)

Comment: @injecteer sure, but providing such an alternative feature to people who does not own a heart beat detecting device would at least show them the change of their heart beat in history -- assuming the library is deterministic :) Also, as far as i tested the apps against the real device there is not a huge difference.

Comment: so, all apps are delivering the heartbeat rates around 60-80 bpm? :)
the question boils down to the accuracy tolerance. Either you provide precise results, or you provide "something". can you imagine a banking app, saying you have around 2k bucks on you account? :)

Comment: I dont have in depth knowledge on the topic but when i simply think about the methods used i believe high accuracy rates are possible. In the case we found some library claiming such an ability this would not go in production before testing against real devices on different people with different properties. But again seeing works like MIT's http://people.csail.mit.edu/mrub/vidmag/ i think high accuracy rates can be achieved.